# MATLAB: Slow convergence of convex optimization algorithm

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization, convex-optimization

I want to speed up the convergence of a convex optimization problem in MATLAB.

My objective function is convex having three parameters and I am using gradient ascent for the maximization.

Right now I am manually writing the iteration with the termination condition being the difference between the new parameter value and old parameter value is very small (around 0.0000001). I cannot terminate based upon the number of iterations because it doesn't guarantee that it has converged to the optimum solution.

So, it takes a lot of time to converge - almost 2 days! Is there any way to speed this up?

Actually my objective function has only three parameters. I know that my first parameter's value should be greater than that of the second.

So starting with the initial condition, the second parameter's value starts increasing rapidly. After it has reached a certain point, the first parameter's value starts increasing rapidly. While the first parameter's value starts increasing, the second parameter's value starts decreasing slowly. Eventually, I have the first parameter's value greater than that of second.

Is there any way to speed up the process? 2 days is a very long time. Furthermore, calculating the gradient is also time consuming. It needs a lot of matrix computations.

I don't want to start with the defined parameter values like parameter1's value greater than that of second. Also it's not necessary that the first parameter always has to be greater than the the second. I just know which parameter value should be greater. Any suggestions?

Comment: Honestly, a little bit of Maths would have helped to understand your question. What is the objective function? What algorithm are you using? How did you implement it? I see only three possible problems: Your algorithm is not a good choice for the objective function, you have bad initial values or your implementation is less than optimal.

Comment: Yep, instead of telling us about the variables and their values, you should give more details about your gradient ascent implementation, particularly your update rule.

Comment: gradient search is a newton type optimization, but it is the slowest of that family. Why don't you try Gaus-Newton (with or without LM) or [BFGS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BFGS_method) if it's non-linear. Most of the time these are a lot faster. complete other solution: maybe you can use [yalmip](http://users.isy.liu.se/johanl/yalmip/pmwiki.php?n=Main.WhatIsYALMIP)

Comment: I think you still would get a more sophisticated answer if you give us your code (at least the part that performs your gradient search) and most important the objective function.

Comment: If your gradients are not analytic, then you shouldn't be using a gradient-based method.  You should at least try a simplex method, but I think Matlab's optimization toolbox has other non-gradient options, as well.  If your gradients are analytic, I definitely agree with @GuntherStruyf.  Try using a gradient-based algorithm with better convergence (BFGS is pretty good).  If neither of these are fast enough, then you need to profile your code (see `help profile`) and try to optimize the function that you're calling.

Answer (score 0):

If the calculation of gradients is very slow and you still want to do a manual implementation you could try this, it will take more steps but could be a lot quicker as the steps are so simple:

Define a stepsize

Try all the points  where your variable moves -1, 0 or 1 times in the direction of the stepsize (3^3 = 27 possibilities)

Pick the best one

If the best one is your previous one, multiply the stepsize with a factor 0.5

Of course the success of this process depends on the properties of your function. Furthermore it should be noted that a much simpler solution could be to set the desired difference to something like 0.0001